# Uri and Filepath for all the raw resources android

Tags: android, uri, filepath, android-resources

I have few files in raw folder of application, i need to have both Uri and filepath for those/all files present in the raw folder

so far, i am able to print all the names of files in raw folder(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540269/1225413)), but not able to get Uri and the file path for them

```
public void listRaw()
{
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++)
    {
        Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
    }
}
```

1. I DO NOT need input stream for those files
2. I need file path and uri for those files
3. Do i need to put all files in assets to get Uri and filepath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7979084/634474

Comment: Since there is no "filepath" of raw resources, you will need to redesign your app to avoid your "need". Resources are not files on the device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path

Comment: @CommonsWare the apk will have resources packaged right? so the raw folder is also packaged under the apk file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand about resources, what about assets?

Comment: There is no "filepath" for an asset, either. These are not files, except on your development machine. Resources and assets are entries in the ZIP file that is the APK. If you need a "filepath", you will have to make a copy of the data into a local file.

Comment: @CommonsWare got your point, got solution to store files locally, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7976663/1225413  , thanks for your time