# How can I play musics from raw folder not SDcard in this music player?

Tags: android

I have 4 classes for my music player :

1:

```
public class AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    // Media Player
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Forward button click event
         * Forwards song specified seconds
         * */
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Backward button click event
         * Backward song to specified seconds
         * */
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event
         * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button
         * Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button
         * Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isShuffle){
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle= true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
             currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
             // play selected song
             playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();            
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
    }   

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
               long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

               // Displaying Total Duration time
               songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
               // Displaying time completed playing
               songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

               // Updating progress bar
               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
               //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
               songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

               // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
        };

    /**
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    /**
     * On Song Playing completed
     * if repeat is ON play same song again
     * if shuffle is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat){
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if(isShuffle){
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else{
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

     }
```

2:

```
public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

3:

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

4:

```
public class Utilities {

    /**
     * Function to convert milliseconds time to
     * Timer Format
     * Hours:Minutes:Seconds
     * */
    public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
        String finalTimerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";

        // Convert total duration into time
           int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
           int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
           int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
           // Add hours if there
           if(hours > 0){
               finalTimerString = hours + ":";
           }

           // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
           if(seconds < 10){ 
               secondsString = "0" + seconds;
           }else{
               secondsString = "" + seconds;}

           finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

        // return timer string
        return finalTimerString;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get Progress percentage
     * @param currentDuration
     * @param totalDuration
     * */
    public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
        Double percentage = (double) 0;

        long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
        long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

        // calculating percentage
        percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

        // return percentage
        return percentage.intValue();
    }

    /**
     * Function to change progress to timer
     * @param progress - 
     * @param totalDuration
     * returns current duration in milliseconds
     * */
    public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
        int currentDuration = 0;
        totalDuration = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
        currentDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);

        // return current duration in milliseconds
        return currentDuration * 1000;
    }
}
```

I have 20 musics in raw folder , in 3rd class in 2nd line musics play from sdcard in this code ..... but I want play my 20 musics in raw folder ......... How can I do it ???

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539715/android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: @goonerdroid , thank you , I referred but I can't understand , can you exactly explain me what should I do for this problem ?? .... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As you have audio files in `Raw` folder, you can achieve it by passing the `resourceId` of the file to `Mediaplayer`.

1. Create a playlist with song names each corresponding to one audio file in raw folder.
   Display it in listview. It's upto you to decide whether to keep actual name and display name same or different. You will have to map them accordingly, if you decide to use different display name than actual name.
2. On selecting the particular item ie.song get the resource id of the corresponding audio file as follows

   ```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {                 
               // Textview to display the audio file name in list
               TextView txtView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
               // the name of audio file in Raw folder, displayed in list
               String fname=txtView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
               // get the resource id
               int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
               // Pass it to mediaplayer   
               MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
               // Start the mediaplayer
               mediaPlayer.start();
           }
       });
   ```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am beginner .... can u explain more in detail ?1) how can I create playlist..... 2)which line in which class should I add your code ??? I HAVE founded this code from a website ... it isn't for me

Comment: Refer [Listview tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: when I close this app in my phone one error about unfortunately closed your app appear ..... why ???