# How can I access files in res/raw folder or any other location in android?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I posted a day ago similar question, but I simplified my problem here so hoping to get resolved. 
I think I know when reading a file with 'filename.ext', I use

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```

But how I can access multiple files? I need a function looks like

```
InputStream inputStream[] = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.*.*);
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Android, how do can I get a list of all files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539715/android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: THank you for the helpful link. I searched similar topics before I post and failed but this is great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place your files in `assets/` instead of `res/raw/`, then something like this might work for you:

```
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    String assetFileNames[] = am.list("");
    InputStream inputStream;
    for(String assetFileName : assetFileNames) {
        inputStream = am.open(assetFileName);
        // Replace with whatever you want to do with the file here
        processAssetFile(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Note that several of the methods above throw `java.io.IOException`, which you'd have to handle in your own implementation.