# Obtaining titles from raw folder

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Student programmer here so please have patience...

I am simply trying to obtain the file names of .mp3 files in the raw folder (in string form). Does anyone have a quick method of doing this? Cheers!

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539715/android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: what are the file formats in your raw folder? only .mp3 or any other types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache [FileUtils](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/io-commons/fileutils/org-apache-commons-io-fileutils-example/)

For example :

```
 for (File f: FileUtils.getFile(MAIN_PATH + "pathOfFolder\\").listFiles()) {

    System.out.println("File Name: " + f.getName());

 }
```

Hope this helps your out