# How to get all media files in /res/raw dynamically?

Tags: android

I want to initialize `MediaPlayer` instances for all of the soundfiles found in `res/raw`:

```
/res/raw/test1.mp3
/res/raw/test2.mp3
/res/raw/testN.mp3
```

Purpose is to play different samples on a button click, without delays.

```
List<MediaPlayer> player = new ArrayList<>();

//TODO how to loop properly?
for (Rawfile file : rawfiles) {
    pl = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.test1);
    player.add(pl);
}
```

Lateron, if eg button2 is clicked:

`player.get(1).start();`

Question: how can I get the `R.raw.*` files dynamically during initialization of the app?

---

Update: the following is quite close, but there are 2 problems:

1) If eg only one file "test.mp3" is placed in my  `/res/raw` folder, the function shows 3 files.
2) How can I then load those files to mediaplayer?

```
public void listRaw(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
I/Raw Asset:: $change
I/Raw Asset:: serialVersionUID
I/Raw Asset:: test
```

Comment: check [android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539715/android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: @ELITE this gives 3 files, as updated above. But I only have one...

Answer (score 3):

For the moment solved as follows, but feels kinda hacky:

```
public static List<Integer> listRawMediaFiles() {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : R.raw.class.getFields()) {
        try {
            ids.add(field.getInt(field));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //compiled app contains files like '$change' or 'serialVersionUID'
            //which are no real media files
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Really forget from where i get this, it can be duplicated any way not my code but works perfectly :

```
 private boolean listFiles(String path) {
        String [] list;
        try {
            list = getAssets().list(path);
            if (list.length > 0) {
                // folder founded 
                for (String file : list) {
                    if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
                        return false;
                }
            } else {
                //file founded
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: What is `listAssetFiles()`? I doubt this really returns the list of /raw files. At least `getAssets().list("/raw")` does not!.

Answer (score 0):

Though undervoted, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539756/2657100) from CommonsWare is comprehensive. The best you can do is iterate over the raw fields by reflection. If you find non-resource fields, you should discard them manually (I see you did it in an answer).

One point: putting files in `raw` directory is done during *development time*, and programming the iteration over `raw` resources is also done during *development time*. It's a problem you should solve before compilation, rather than finding out what files you have in *run time*, that is, you should list the files by name in your code.